# Defining a function to a Row

Tags: zend-framework

im making an application and i need to implement diferent level of user permits.

I coul have the function

```
$this->view->users->hasPermits($this->view->user);
```

By declaring a function on the model, an things could be easy to implement. But i would like to be able to have the next function doing the same:

```
$this->view->user->hasPermits();
```

Is there a way to do this? do i need to extend the Zend_Db_Table_Row class? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) for this.

There is a  [Zend ACL tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6qsSnLfcmE).

Answer (score 1):

If $user is a Zend_Db_Table_Row from the Zend_Db_Table $users, than in User you could perform the method like so:

```
public function hasPermits()
{
    return $this->getTable()->hasPermits($this);
}
```